# Build a correlation circle with Python - Error ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3) into shape (28)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to build a correlation circle, basically, it allows to measure to which extend the Eigenvalue / Eigenvector of a variable is correlated to the principal components (dimensions) of a dataset.

Something like this :

[image]

Here is my code :

```py
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#chargement données
X = pd.read_excel("mortalitePaysUE.xlsx",sheet_name=0,header=0,index_col=0)

#nombre d'observations
n = X.shape[0]

#nombre de variable
p = X.shape[0]
print(p)
#transformation - centrage/réduction
sc = StandardScaler()
Z = sc.fit_transform(X)
print(Z)
print("-------------")

#moyenne
print("Moyenne : ")
print(np.mean(X,axis=0))
print("-------------")


#ecart-type
print("Ecart type : ")
print(np.std(X,axis=1,ddof=0))
print("-------------")

#acp
acp = PCA(svd_solver='full')
coord = acp.fit_transform(Z)
eigval = (n-1)/n*acp.explained_variance_
print(eigval)

#screen plot 
#plt.plot(np.arange(1,p+1),eigval)
#plt.title("Décès en 1990 selon le genre")
#plt.xlabel("Numéro de facteur")
#plt.ylabel("Valeur propre")
#plt.show()

#positionnement des individus dans le premier plan
fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,12))
axes.set_xlim(-6,6) #même limites en abscisse
axes.set_ylim(-6,6) #et en ordonnée
#placement des étiquettes des observations
for i in range(n):
 plt.annotate(X.index[i],(coord[i,0],coord[i,1]))
#ajouter les axes
plt.plot([-6,6],[0,0],color='silver',linestyle='-',linewidth=1)
plt.plot([0,0],[-6,6],color='silver',linestyle='-',linewidth=1)
#affichage
plt.show()

#racine carrée des valeurs propres
sqrt_eigval = np.sqrt(eigval)

#corrélation des variables avec les axes
corvar = np.zeros((p,p))

for k in range(p):
 corvar[:,k] = acp.components_[k,:] * sqrt_eigval[k]

#afficher la matrice des corrélations variables x facteurs
#print(corvar)

#cercle des corrélations
fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))
axes.set_xlim(-1,1)
axes.set_ylim(-1,1)
#affichage des étiquettes (noms des variables)
for j in range(p):
 plt.annotate(X.columns[j],(corvar[j,0],corvar[j,1]))

#ajouter les axes
plt.plot([-1,1],[0,0],color='silver',linestyle='-',linewidth=1)
plt.plot([0,0],[-1,1],color='silver',linestyle='-',linewidth=1)

#ajouter un cercle
cercle = plt.Circle((0,0),1,color='blue',fill=False)
axes.add_artist(cercle)
```

The problem is that i got an error and i can't display the circle. And i can't resolve the error

```
    corvar[:,k] = acp.components_[k,:] * sqrt_eigval[k]
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3) into shape (28)
```

Can anyone help me to fix this please :) Thanks in advance !

Comment: You have a typo at `p=X.shape[1]`. So corvar[:,k] has incorrect number of rows, shape of corvar is set by p, hence the error.

Comment: ok that was a stupid mistake ! thanks for your help :)